# Shading parts of fitch-style natural deduction proofs

Tags: backgrounds, logic, proof-package, fitch

I'm using the fitch package (the one written by Prof. Selinger and is now maintained, I believe, by Richard Zach) for pedagogical purposes -- as I suspect many people do.

It would be helpful to be able to highlight parts of proofs with shading. I'm afraid I don't really know how to do that. I know how to put a whole proofs inside a shaded environment, e.g., with the mdframed package.

I've included a MWE for a simple fitch-proof, as well as an image of what I'd like to be able to shade with a box drawn in by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fitch}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{nd}
  \hypo {1} {P \lor Q} \by{}{}%
  \hypo {2} {P \rightarrow R} \by{}{}%
  \hypo {3} {Q \rightarrow R} \by{}{}%
  \open%
  \hypo {4} {P} \by{}{}%
  \have {5} {R} \by{}{}%
  \close%
  \open%
  \hypo {6} {Q} \by{}{}%
  \have {7} {R} \by{}{}%
  \close%
  \have {8} {R} \by{}{}%
\end{nd}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please check code compiles before posting. You cannot use `standalone` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty easily highlight the relevant part of the proof using a box by placing `tikzmark`s appropriately and drawing a `tikzpicture` afterwards.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700683/  i gwestiwn Bernhard: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/700671/    
\usepackage{fitch}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{nd}
    \hypo {1} {P \lor Q} \by{}{}%
    \hypo {2} {P \rightarrow R} \by{}{}%
    \hypo {3} {Q\tikzmark{a} \rightarrow R} \by{}{}%
    \open 
    \hypo {4} {\tikzmarknode{b}{P}} \by{}{}
    \have {5} {\tikzmarknode{c}{R}} \by{\tikzmarknode{d}{\strut}}{}
    \close
    \open
    \hypo {6} {Q} \by{}{}%
    \have {7} {R} \by{}{}%
    \close
    \have {8} {R} \by{}{}%
  \end{nd}
\end{displaymath}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [fit=({pic cs:a} |- b) (b) (c) ($(d.south)!.75!(c |- d.south)$),draw=red] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: highlight part of proof using red box]

If you actually want to shade that part of the proof, as opposed to drawing around it, things are considerably trickier. Until the proof is constructed, you don't know where to shade; after it is constructed, you can't easily shade beneath it.

One approach would be to put the proof inside a `tikzpicture`. Then we can use the `backgrounds` library to shade the relevant sub-proof after the proof is constructed. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700683/  i gwestiwn Bernhard: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/700671/
\usepackage{fitch}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node [align=center] {%
    $\begin{nd}
      \hypo {1} {P \lor Q} \by{}{}%
      \hypo {2} {P \rightarrow R} \by{}{}%
      \hypo {3} {Q\tikzmark{e} \rightarrow R} \by{}{}%
      \open 
      \hypo {4} {\subnode{f}{P}} \by{}{}
      \have {5} {\subnode{g}{R}} \by{\subnode{h}{\strut}}{}
      \close
      \open
      \hypo {6} {Q} \by{}{}%
      \have {7} {R} \by{}{}%
      \close
      \have {8} {R} \by{}{}%
    \end{nd}$
  };
  \scoped[on background layer]
  {
    \node [fit=({pic cs:e} |- f) (f) (g) ($(h.south)!.75!(g |- h.south)$),fill=cyan!25] {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: shaded subproof]

Comment: Basically the same method as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370815/2693). I really ought to finish the package version of this.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. I'd not seen that (as far as I remember). Interesting. I guess you mean my method is akin to your more complicated version? But I'm not sure whether the simpler one would work in this case. `tikzmark` works in maths and text modes, which makes the markup a bit simpler. And your simpler case wouldn't work for shading, would it? Which was what the OP asked for.

Comment: @AlanMunn Actually, your version almost works for the boxing case. I guess the maths stuff is OK since it's not ending up in your nodes. Could it be used to box the sub-proof? That would definitely be interesting. I don't see a way to do shading that way, though?

Comment: Yes the math isn't the issue. I don't know what the sub-proof is, so I can't answer that question. :)  I was assuming shading would work just by adding `fill` to the node (like [this version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386274/2693)) but somehow that doesn't work in this example.

Comment: @AlanMunn So shade over the top of the text?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why that doesn't work in the proof example, but it does in the algorithm example.

Comment: @AlanMunn How does pgf associate saved positions with current references on the second run? If I look at the `aux` file, I have no idea what the relationship between the saved locations and the defined `\tikzmk`s are. Does it just rely on ordering? If I only include the `fitch` proof, the numbers start from 2. If I include the algorithm, they start from 1.

Comment: I have no idea. ;)